# Create a Contact in Outlook 2016

Tags: vba, outlook

I have searched and found multiple suggestions for using VBA and creating a new Outlook contact, none of which seem to work.

I am attempting to create new contacts using an Excel spreadsheet for the data.  I can create new emails from this same data, I just can't get the right code to create a new contact form.

All the suggestions I've found on other bulletin boards seem to be for older versions of Outlook and apparently they have changed since they were posted.

This is is where I'm having issues:

```
Public Sub CreateNewContact()
Dim contactItem  As Outlook.contactItem 
Set contactItem = Application.CreateItem(olContactItem)    
contactItem.FullName = "Greg Thatcher"
contactItem.Email1Address = "gregt@xobni.com"
contactItem.BusinessTelephoneNumber = "415 555 1212"
contactItem.HomeTelephoneNumber = "415 555 1234"
contactItem.MobileTelephoneNumber = "415 555 1236"
contactitem.display    
End Sub

'''
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Comment: What is the issue? That looks perfectly fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with your code too (run-time Error 438). I solved the problems with this code (I added `Dim myOutlook As Outlook.Application` and `Set contactItem = myOutlook.CreateItem(olContactItem)`):

```
Public Sub CreateNewContact()
   Dim myOutlook As Outlook.Application
   Dim contactItem As contactItem

   Set myOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   Set contactItem = myOutlook.CreateItem(olContactItem)
   
    contactItem.FullName = "Greg Thatcher"
    contactItem.Email1Address = "gregt@xobni.com"
    contactItem.BusinessTelephoneNumber = "415 555 1212"
    contactItem.HomeTelephoneNumber = "415 555 1234"
    contactItem.MobileTelephoneNumber = "415 555 1236"
    contactItem.display
End Sub
```

Comment: It errors on the "Dim myoutlook as outlook.application" with "User defined type not defined"

Comment: Add the rederence: Tool > References > Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library

Comment: Library is already checked and I have another module that creates Outlook Emails and it works fine.  The Set command is identical.  It's got me baffled completely.  It must be something simple that I'm just not seeing because I've been looking at it too long.

Comment: Try this: `Dim myOutlook As Object` and `Dim contactItem As Object`. Pay attention, the reference Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library has to be installed.

Comment: LIbrary is installed and I have tried the Dims as Objects.. When I do that it errors (438 - Object does not support this property or method)) on the contactitem.Fullname line.  It feels like it is not creating the Contact card and thus not finding the field names to fill.

Comment: When I use this code it brings up an empty Email, not a Contact form;

Comment: Public Sub CreateNewContact()
   Dim myOutlook As Object
   Dim contactItem As Object

   Set myOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   Set contactItem = myOutlook.CreateItem(olContactItem)
   
    'contactItem.FullName = "Greg Thatcher"
    'contactItem.Email1Address = "gregt@xobni.com"
    'contactItem.BusinessTelephoneNumber = "415 555 1212"
    'contactItem.HomeTelephoneNumber = "415 555 1234"
    'contactItem.MobileTelephoneNumber = "415 555 1236"
    contactItem.display
End Sub

Comment: Could you please show me a prrintscreen of the installed references?

Comment: Not sure how to paste a screenprint into this. I have the following,VB basic for Apps, MS Excel 16.0 Obj Lib, OLE automation, MS Office 16 obj lib, MS forms 2.0 obj lib, atpvbaen.xls and Shockwavae.flash

Comment: I GOT IT!  I didn't have the MS Office Object Library loaded.  I was seeing the MS Excel Obj. Lib and thinkiing Office.  I knew it was something small that I couldn't see because I was looking at it too long and seeing what I wanted to.  Thank you for your patience and assistance.  I really appreciate it

Comment: No problem :)... please mark the answer as correct.